# Copy one table to another except the id filed

Tags: mysql, copy, field

I want to copy table1 to table2 except for the 'id' field because i want the 'id' in table2 to increment automatically.

Here is one of the solution i have tried... but not working:
"INSERT INTO table2 SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table1 WHERE member_id = '53'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select NULL in place of the id, if you don't (for whatever reason) want to name the columns.

Assuming both of your tables have the columns `member_id`, `field1`, `field1`, `field3`, in that order, you can do:

`insert into table2 select NULL, field1, field2, field3 from table1 where member_id = '53';`

NOTE: you must provide a value for ALL columns, using this format.

Comment: This answer means he has to update the query every time he adds a new column.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to fill all columns of the destination table, then you need to name the columns you want to fill

```
INSERT INTO table2 (table2_f1, table2_f2, table2_f3)
SELECT field1, field2, field3 
FROM table1 
WHERE member_id = '53'
```

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO table2 (table2_f1, table2_f2, table2_f3)
SELECT field1, field2, field3 
FROM table1

You don't need to specify id if you set it auto_increment

Answer (score -1):

The best answer........
USE TEMPORARY TABLE!

example table a and table b
a have 3 column
b have 6 column
both table has first column id.(but we do not wish column id copy to  table b)

---

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp AS SELECT * FROM a WHERE id=5;
UPDATE temp
SET id = NULL;
INSERT INTO b
SELECT *,'EFG',33,'ABCD' FROM temp;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp;
```

---